# Newbie how to raise/trigger events in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need a litle help here.... I'm just getting started with C# and I need to raise an event when a bool value changes. I have a class with this:

```
using System;

namespace WOCA
{
    public class Arduino
    {

        public event EventHandler Disconnected;

        **protected virtual void OnDisconnected()
        {
            EventHandler handler = Disconnected;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }**

        private bool _isconnected;
        public bool IsConnected
        {
            get 
            {
                 return _isconnected;
            }
        }

        #region Methods
        public void Connect()
        {
            //TODO implement code to connect
            _isconnected = true;
        }
        public void Disconnect()
        {
            //TODO implement code to connect
            _isconnected = false;

        }

        #endregion Methods

    }
}
```

But how to I raise/trigger an event when _isconnected changes value?

Comment: Call `OnDisconnected()`?

Comment: Also, put the relevant call inside the `IsConnected` property setter (make it writable!) and don't ever touch `_isconnected` manually (except from within the property). This is why properties exist.

Comment: if you change your property IsConnected so it also has a setter...and call the event from the setter...then from Connect and Disconnect instead of _isconnected = true/false - put IsConnected = true/false

Comment: Use a setter on IsConnected.. check, if (value != this._isconnected) and invoke the event handler

Comment: I disagree with making the `IsConnected` property writeable. The connection state is encapsulated by the `Connect`/`Disconnect` functions - the `IsConnected` property is simply a way of returning state, not setting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all the code there, you just need the trigger...

```
public void Disconnect()
{
    _isconnected = false;
    OnDisconnected();
}
```

Comment: OK, I added that to the Disconnect () method and it does go into the handler however the If statment is never true - I suspect I'm still missing something!               if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

Comment: You probably haven't hooked up to the event externally...`var arduino = new Arduino(); arduino.Disconnected += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine("Disconnected!");`

Comment: Yep, thats what it was! Told you guys I'm new to all this!

Answer (score 2):

it should be simple

```
    public event EventHandler Disconnected;

    protected virtual void OnDisconnected()
    {
        EventHandler handler = Disconnected;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    private bool _isconnected;
    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isconnected;
        }
        private set
        {
            if (!value && _isConnected)
            {
                OnDisconnected();
            }
            _isconnected = value;
        }
    }

    #region Methods
    public void Connect()
    {
        //TODO implement code to connect
        IsConnected = true;
    }
    public void Disconnect()
    {
        //TODO implement code to connect
        IsConnected = false;

    }

    #endregion Methods
```

Comment: This could be improved - you probably wouldn't want to keep raising the `Disconnected` event if the connection isn't connected to start with.

Comment: Disconnected is always equal to NULL

Comment: +1. I also changed so that the event will only trigger if the state goes from connected to disconnected

Comment: @user1779064: You have to subscribe to the event from somewhere: `var myArduino = new Arduino(); myArduino.Disconnected += OnArduinoDisconnected;`

Comment: In another class where you are using this class, you will have to write code like below.

YourClass c = new YourClass();
c.Disconnected += eventHandler_Disconnected;

void eventHandler_Disconnected(EventArgs e)
{
   // when event is raised, the control will come here
}

Comment: I still don't agree that `IsConnected` is the way to modify the state. For me, the workflow is clearly enforced by the `Connect`/`Disconnect` methods and as such the OP's code seemed fine to me - there could be more actions required for the connection to be truly severed, `IsConnected` is public and as such could allow the state to be set without ever going through those method calls. Not only that, `IsConnected` is asking a question and therefore makes much more sense as a read-only property.

Comment: Thanks for the edit jgauffin. I think the event should be raised after setting _isconnected. Because, if the property IsConnected is accessed inside event handler, it would still return true.